Opening ReadOnly template changes file name
When I use the sub below, it opens the DAILY OBSERVATIONS.xltm workbook but appends a number to the end. I need it to open as the original filename because I copy sheets from the new file back into the template.
Sub SaveWithDate()
Dim fname As String
fname = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Const SubName As String = "SaveWithDate"   'The name of this routine
Const SheetName As String = "OBSERVATIONS"      'The name of the sheet that can use this sub
If ActiveSheet.Name <> SheetName Then
  MsgBox "This macro can only be called from '" & SheetName & "'", vbOKOnly, SubName
  Exit Sub
End If
If ActiveWorkbook.Name <> "DAILY OBSERVATIONS.xltm" Then
    MsgBox "This macro can only be called from 'DAILY OBSERVATIONS.xltm. You already renamed this workbook.'", vbOKOnly, SubName
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim fileName As String
Dim currentDate As String

' Get the current date in the format YYYYMMDD
currentDate = Format(Now, "yyyymmdd")

' Specify the file name with the current date
fileName = "L:\DAILY OBSERVATIONS\" & currentDate & " DAILY OBSERVATIONS"

' Save the workbook with the specified file name
' ThisWorkbook.SaveAs fileName
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=fileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
Workbooks.Open ("L:\DAILY OBSERVATIONS\DAILY OBSERVATIONS.xltm")


End Sub


By your code stating it cannot be run in any other workbook, it seems that workbook is already open and you are opening another copy which Excel will then append the number.  If it is already open, why are you opening it again?  You cannot have two workbooks open with the same name.

What you open a template by double-clicking in Explorer, Excel treats the file for what it is: a template. So it opens a copy and puts a 1 behind the name of the file. If you want to open the template for editing, open Excel and use File, Open and point at the template.

The macro saves the template as a .xlsm file. This file is updated with the day's data. I want the data saved back to the template so the next day a file is created by the macro, those tabs are current. Can I just save the new file back as a .xltm file overwriting the existing?

I ended up just recording a macro and tweaking it to work how I need.
Dim currentDate As String
currentDate = Format(Now, "yyyymmdd")
    Workbooks.Open fileName:="L:\DAILY OBSERVATIONS\DAILY OBSERVATIONS.xltm", _
        Editable:=True
    Windows(currentDate & " DAILY OBSERVATIONS.xlsm").Activate
End Sub

